# How to make another kappa

Tags: symbols

Good afternoon! 
I would like you to tell me how to make another "kappa"? I mean, how to make the default kappa look like the \ae symbol? I need to use such variant in formula but I always get warnings when using "\ae" in equations. What should I do? I tried to use \varkappa but I don't like how it looks. 
Thank you for your attention and also sorry for my Enlgish.

I've read you comments and made the following code:

```
\newcommand{\Kappa}{\text{\ae}}
```

[image]

The problem is that inside \begin{align}\end{align} it looks like on the screen. Inside other environments such as [ ] or $ $ it looks like the normal kappa: ae. What should I do?

I tried to use "mbox" instead of "text" but the problem remains. Only here this letter looks wrong. Is it possible to avoid these misunderstandings?

Comment: You can override the `\kappa` command to call the `\ae` command. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yep, that sounds like what I really needed to find. Thank you.

Comment: Could you mark an answer as accepted or post your solution and accept that? It seems you found the answer you were looking for and it helps the community when questions are not left without an accepted solution.

Comment: Sure, but how? It's about 2 days as I'm registered here.

Comment: Welcome to the community! There is a check-mark to the left of a response, along with up and down arrows for voting for or against different answers. Click on those! Finally, questions here are typically restricted to be only a single part, perhaps this new question of yours belongs in another post...

Comment: æ has ***nothing*** to do with the Greek kappa. You might think they're similar, your readers won't.

Comment: Then what should I do to use the symbol I'm looking for? In my university everybody calls the symbol \ae as "kappa" so. Anyway.

Comment: @MGMKLML Maybe you're thinking of `\varkappa` (available in the amssymb package)?

Comment: I wrote: " I tried to use \varkappa but I don't like how it looks".

Answer (score 12):

You seem to be attaching meaning to a particular graphical representation of a symbol, but you shouldn't.

When hand writing, the variant kappa you seem to be discussing about often has two small loops, but typographical representations usually omit them. Those loops are probably responsible for you mistaking the symbol with the letter “æ” (used in Danish, Norwegian, Icelandic and Faroese and sometimes in English and French) that's a completely different thing.

You may not like the symbol `\varkappa` as provided by the `amssymb` package, but anyway you have to stick with some symbol you are able to reproduce and that's a realization of what Unicode calls GREEK KAPPA SYMBOL U+03F0.

Using æ for this is simply wrong.

You can get a “looping” realization within the Solomos font provided by the Greek Font Society and included in TeX Live (possibly also in MiKTeX).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{solomos}{}
\DeclareErrorFont{U}{solomos}{m}{n}{10}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{solomos}{m}{n}{
  <-> s*[1.1]  gsolomos8r
}{}

\newcommand{\vkappa}{\text{\usefont{U}{solomos}{m}{n}\symbol{'153}}}

\begin{document}

A kappa $\kappa$ and its variant $\vkappa$.

This is different from \ae{} and should not be confused with it.

The symbol $\varkappa$ is just a graphic variant, there's
no meaning implied in the graphical appearance.

\huge $\vkappa$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I seem to call wrong the letter. Okay, how to put without any troubles \ae in formulas?

Comment: @MGMKLML I've never seen “æ” used in formulas.

Comment: A very fine answer, apart from one tiny point of pedantry. AFAIK æ isn't really a French letter. It gets used in Latin and Greek borrowings, but then it did in English too. And still does, very occasionally. Encyclopædia Britannica being the go-to example :P

Comment: @Au101 Fixed, thanks for being pedant! `:-)`

Comment: As far as I know the letter `\ae` is used in Phonetics too, especially for Medieval or Old English, but I've never seen it as a variable name

Comment: æ is definitely used in phonetics. It's the IPA representation of the vowel in c**a**t (in most peoples' accents, anyway, English has so many accents, I don't think you'll ever find a vowel that's pronounced the same by everyone)

Comment: When we write the symbols on paper we write kappa close to ae, I mean, it just looks like ae. So that's why I'm asking you.

Comment: @MGMKLML When writing by hand, the Cyrillic lowercase д (corresponding to Latin d) has a shape very similar to the Latin g, but it's a Cyrillic d notwithstanding. If the handwritten form of kappa is similar to æ, it still remains a kappa.

Comment: @egreg Seriously? Haha. I know. Anyway I would like to put on ae inside any formula and it's the second question if it's used in formulas in real life or not.

Comment: @MGMKLML `\textnormal{\ae}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `renewcommand` to redefine the `kappa` function if you'd like. The following code should do it:

```
\renewcommand\kappa{\text{\ae}}
```

Include this at the top of your file and all `kappa` calls should show the `ae` symbol. Notice that I have also wrapped `ae` in a `text` command, so that you won't get any warnings about being in a math environment. Typically warnings like this are nothing to worry about, but I understand it's nice to make them go away.

Comment: I don't think that redefining a rather prominent symbol like `\kappa` is very useful

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Nor do I, but it seems to be what OP is asking for...

Comment: I've decided to define a new command called \Kappa, using your idea. Thank you a lot.

Comment: You'll get different results when the context is upright and italic; for instance, in the statement of a theorem (usually typeset in italics), you'll get an italic *æ* whereas in normal text you'll get an upright æ.

Comment: How to get everywhere what I need?